# Polymorphic return type

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism

A function reads ID from a stream of bytes. It knows the size of id - can be 4 or 8 bytes. How to make the return type polymorphic?

(Pseudocode:)

```
    class (Integral a) => IdSize a where
      size :: a -> Int

    instance IdSize Int32 ...

    instance IdSize Int64 ...

    data Data = Data (Map (IdSize a) String)
    readData :: Data (Map (IdSize a) String)
    readId :: (forall a. IdSize a) => a -- kind of this, but not right
```

This readId would require IdSize a instance from the caller, but the caller doesn't know the size. Similarly, Map returned by readData needs to be polymorphic, but the caller doesn't know the actual type. The type will be known to the functions using the Map.

Comment: As a straw man, how about just using `Either Int32 Int64` everywhere you claim you need something "polymorphic"?

Comment: Of course, it is polymorphic. In Java I can declare a return type Object and return any subclass. Here I was looking to express a similar idea. The caller wouldn't care what's returned, until it passes the returned value to a function that can figure out what to do. Existential quantification can get me some way along this path, but I need to study and experiment some more to see what's the next question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is not "polymorphic" if it can have only two types. That's just a disjoint union of two types, or a "sum" type.

```
import Data.Int

data Idx = I32 Int32
         | I64 Int64
  deriving (Show)

readId 4 _ = I32 0x12345678
readId _ _ = I64 0x1234567812345678

idSize (I32 _) = 4
idSize _       = 8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input = () -- this would be your input stream
  let idx1 = readId 4 input
  let idx2 = readId 8 input
  putStrLn $ "idx 1: size " ++ (show $ idSize idx1) ++ " value: " ++ (show idx1)
  putStrLn $ "idx 2: size " ++ (show $ idSize idx2) ++ " value: " ++ (show idx2)
  return ()
```

When you really do need more flexibility in the type signature of your data type, such as when you are building an abstract syntax tree that you want to constrain to well-typed constructions, GADTs are a nice approach: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT

Here's the example with GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

import           Data.Int

data Idx a where
  I32 :: Int32 -> Idx Int32
  I64 :: Int64 -> Idx Int64

deriving instance Show (Idx a)

readId32 :: t -> Idx Int32
readId32 _ = I32 0x12345678

readId64 :: t -> Idx Int64
readId64 _ = I64 0x1234567812345678

idSize :: Num a => Idx t -> a
idSize (I32 _) = 4
idSize _       = 8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let idx1 = readId32 ()
  let idx2 = readId64 ()
  putStrLn $ "idx 1: size " ++ (show $ idSize idx1) ++ " value: " ++ (show idx1)
  putStrLn $ "idx 2: size " ++ (show $ idSize idx2) ++ " value: " ++ (show idx2)
  return ()
```

I'm not sure if this is quite what you were after, but it does let you specialize the type so that you can't mix `Idx Int32`s with `Idx Int64`s, but you can still write polymorphic `Idx a` functions like `idSize`.

Comment: Yes, using union is a simple answer to the current problem. I was hoping to find a expression that could constrain the Map better. Map (Either Int32 Int64) String permits a mix of Int32 and Int64 as the key. It would be nice to constrain it in such a way that only one of the types is used as the key throughout. (and it's not the only thing that depends on the id size, so whereas for now I'll use Either, it'd be great to have it constrained tighter)

Comment: I updated with a GADT version that will not permit mixing Idx Int32 and Idx Int64.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. It seems I might need Existential quantification after all. Is there a way to write mkH with Idx defined like in your case? The pattern is like so: caller uses mkH :: Int -> H to construct a H; then can use it using use :: (a->b) -> H -> b. See my latest answer below (don't know how to paste the code in the comment)

Comment: @SassaNF I still think you are pulling out too-big guns to shoot this bird. If you want one map for each type, just use `(Map Int32 String, Map Int64 String)`; or, if your decoding function will certainly be decoding either all big IDs or all small IDs, just use `Either (Map Int32 String) (Map Int64 String)`. I think, when there's only two types involved, you can get a really long way using very simple, old-fashioned types.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am trying to imagine what the user code for the function that uses maps with keys of either type look like. Do you mean old-fashioned pattern matching f (Left m) = lookup readInt32 m; f (Right m) = lookup readInt64 m? I think the longer the path between readInt* and lookup, the harder it is going to be on the user code to organize and maintain two otherwise identical pieces of code.

Comment: @SassaNF I don't (yet) understand the question. What are `readInt32` and `readInt64`? (...and what does "user code" mean as opposed to just "code"?)

Comment: @DanielWagner readInt32 and readInt64 are the functions that end up reading id of corresponding sizes - see other answers for context. I didn't mention them initially, but clearly they will exist in some form, as their return type is different. Now, because their return type is different, try to wire a function that uses Map and Ids of both kinds. This function will be "user code", the code which someone else writes without knowing the internals of the implementation. For example, a mere lookup of a String becomes a nightmare with two branches.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ok, we can solve some of this using additional wrapper type:

```
        {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, ExistentialQuantification #-}

        import Data.Int

        data Idx = forall a. IdSize a => Idx a

        instance Show Idx where
          show (Idx a) = show a

        class (Integral a, Show a) => IdSize a where
          size :: a -> Int

        instance IdSize Int32 where
          size _ = 4

        instance IdSize Int64 where
          size _ = 8

        readId :: Int -> Idx
        readId 4 = Idx (4 :: Int32)
        readId _ = Idx (8 :: Int64)

        main = print $ readId 8
```

Then perhaps Data will hold a Map Id String.

Comment: Note that is semantically the same as just returning the size directly as `Int` from `readId` because that's the only operation you are able to do on `Idx`.

Comment: @is7s sure, I forgot them after experimenting with all sorts.

Comment: @shang that's true for the caller - the caller can only do that one thing. The trick is in other functions that will be able to use the particular instance of Idx. See my later answer for example pattern. The caller of mkH there cannot do anything with IdSize a - in that sense the caller is polymorphic in result type of the function mkH - but the caller can construct a function that can use the instance of IdSize a to access the map in the same H from which IdSize a is taken. Also, readId is so stupid only in this example; in real app it is readId :: M a for a particular monad M.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked to meet my requirements:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification #-}

    import Data.Int
    import Data.Typeable
    import qualified Data.Map as M

    data H = forall a. IdSize a => H a (M.Map a String)

    class (Integral a, Show a, Typeable a) => IdSize a where
      size :: a -> Int
      readId :: a

    instance IdSize Int32 where
      size _ = 4
      readId = 4

    instance IdSize Int64 where
      size _ = 8
      readId = 8

    use :: (forall a. IdSize a => a -> M.Map a String -> b) -> H -> b
    use f (H i m) = f i m

    idSize :: H -> Int
    idSize (H i _) = size i

    mkH :: Int -> H
    mkH 4 = H (4 :: Int32) (M.singleton (4 :: Int32) "int32")
    mkH _ = H (8 :: Int64) (M.singleton (8 :: Int64) "int64")

    main = print $ use (M.lookup . const readId) $ mkH 4
```

mkH can be used to construct a H, which is opaque to the caller. The caller then can pass a function to use, which will deconstruct H and invoke the given function. The function must be RankN polymorphic - it should work with any IdSize instance. That's the design intention to hide the implementation of IdSize.